# Is there any opensource HTML editor like stackoverflow?

Tags: html-editor

I want to setup my technology blog，and I want to install one good html editor for my blog site, which is suitable for codes. I found that the editor of stackoverflow is pretty good, I want to know is there any open source editor like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

StackOverflow uses [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/).

**2014 update: WMD is marked as obsolete.**

Comment: WMD moved to [pagedown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) now

Comment: What do you mean **WMD is marked as obsolete.**?

Answer (score 3):

1. [WMD Editor Reverse Engineered](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/)
2. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36179/whats-the-deal-with-the-wmd-editor