# HTML editor like Stack Overflow

Tags: html, editor

I want an editor just like Stack Overflow where I can write code(should look like code) as well as image and corresponding HTML should be generated.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any opensource HTML editor like stackoverflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147330/is-there-any-opensource-html-editor-like-stackoverflow)

Comment: The Best Editor that I Found out as far is Ckeditor, distributed by Amazon Web Services. It is completely Free, beautiful and Easy to use. You can find it at https://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 15):

[EnhPageDown](https://github.com/benahm/EnhPageDown) is an Enhanced version of the Stackoverflow [PageDown Editor](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/).
Also have a look at its [demo](http://benahm.github.io/EnhPageDown/public_html/)

Comment: but I want to write codes like stack they use `` tag

Comment: It works exactly stackoverflow, stackoverflow also uses both `` and four spaces for code

Comment: @PraveenGowdaIV github link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @200OK link fixed

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the project from https://github.com/benahm/EnhPageDown. Copied the files from ````EnhPageDown-master\public_html``` to my project. Copied the code from ```EnhPageDown-master\public_html\index.html```. I also had to include `jquery` in the project.

Answer (score 4):

Stackoverflow uses Markdown for text formatting.  You can use an editor like this:

http://www.aloha-editor.org/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a offline program for this but you can certainly use an online html editor like: [Online Html editor](http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/) , for a more fancy, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and more reliable and user-friendly code editor [Figget](https://figget.io)

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is a what you see is what you get editor (WHSIWYG). An editor like this allows you to type in words and paste in picture, and the HTML will be generated from that.

There are a ton of these out there, a simple google search turns up hundreds. Dreamweaver is one that is pretty well known.

Be aware, these editors are great at speeding up workflow, but any developer worth their salt can hand code. It's nice to be able to take shortcuts and work faster with editors like this, but I would suggest learning actual HTML and understanding how the editor works before using one.

Comment: I want also **Paste code** not only type in words and paste in picture

Comment: You can paste in code as well. Most editors of this type have some sort of design view and code view. So you can choose between using the actual code or pasting in the images/words.

Answer (score 0):

I find my ans As I told I want show the code which should looks like code **http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/**

best site for this